# In Rails, how can you restrict users to specific locations or computers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to restrict users, allowing them to clock in/out only while they are using a company computer or onsite. Is there a way to do either of these. I would use IP or hostname, but we have a dynamic IP and the hostname is generated from the IP so neither will prove useful in this case since we are behind the ISP's gateway/firewall.

Comment: This is kinda not the answer you want, but most ISP's provide static IP's on demand, with a little fee probably.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to put a SSL (TLS) client certificate on every computer you want to allow access, then have your HTTP server ask for a valid certificate before allowing the user to connect to your Rails app. With nginx, for example, the configuration could look a bit like this:

```
server {
    listen        443;
    ssl on;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client optional;

    # $ssl_client_verify now contains the result of the certificate check,
    # so you could just do something like this somewhere in your config:

    if($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
        return 403;
    }

    # ...
}
```

The server.crt file is a regular SSL certificate you'd get from a SSL cert shop. The ca.crt (Certificate Authority) file is one you generate yourself. You'd then generate sign a number of client certificates with your CA certificate, and tell nginx to only accept certificates signed by your CA.  [Here's a helpful article that shows you how.](http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi)

This approach would require you to make and securely store a CA certificate, generate (ideally) one certificate per computer you want to allow, and add a client cert to every machine that needs access, so it's quite a bit of work. You also have to make very sure that your users can't just export the client cert and install it on their home PC.